# Rename multiple files in the same folder

Tags: windows-7

I have a bunch of files in the one folder called:

```
photo1.jpeg
photo2.jpeg
photo3.jpeg
```

etc

I would like to rename them all to

```
south_africa_2010_photo1.jpeg
south_africa_2010_photo2.jpeg
south_africa_2010_photo3.jpeg
```

at the same time.

What is a good way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You can try `ren` command in cmd. Firstly, go to the folder that all of your files are in by `cd` command in Power Shell which is more flexible and powerful.

```
Dir | Rename-Item –NewName { $_.name –replace “ “,”south_africa_2010_” }
```

Disclaimer : It's just an example command and I am not responsible for any outcome.

Else, in easy way, you can try this [Bulk Rename Utility](http://www.bulkrenameutility.co.uk/) . and some other ways are [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/111859/how-to-batch-rename-files-in-windows-4-ways-to-rename-multiple-files/).

Answer (score 4):

From Windows Explorer:

1. Select all the files in the folder (press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> - <kbd>A</kbd>)
2. Right-click the first file, choose Rename
3. Type `south_africa_2010_photo(1).jpeg`
4. Press <kbd>Return</kbd>

Your files will now be named:

```
south_africa_2010_photo(1).jpeg
south_africa_2010_photo(2).jpeg
...
south_africa_2010_photo(n).jpeg
```

Comment: Interesting approach but with the parens, the result isn't quite what was requested.  Also, if there are gaps in the numbers on some of the files, they get renumbered.

Comment: @NicoleHamilton Thanks for the comment. What do you mean by "gaps in the numbers"?

Comment: Suppose you have `photo1.jpeg`, `photo3.jpeg` and `photo4.jpeg` but no `photo2.jpeg`.  `photo3.jpeg` and `photo4.jpeg` will get renumbered.

Comment: @NicoleHamilton - I see. This has never been an issue with me. The date/time of the photos are more important than an arbitrary filename...

Comment: +1. This is very less known feature of Windows Explorer..

Answer (score 2):

This kind of thing is a lot easier with a Unix shell on Windows.  For example, here's how you might do it either using [Cygwin `bash`](http://cygwin.org) or my own [Hamilton C shell](http://hamiltonlabs.com/Cshell.htm).

C shell:

```
foreach i (photo*.jpeg) mv $i south_africa_2010_$i; end
```

bash:

```
for i in photo*.jpeg; do mv "$i" "south_africa_2010_$i"; done
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try **[Massive File Renamer](https://ivanrf.com/en/portfolio-posts/massive-file-renamer/)**.

This software will allow you to easily **rename** multiple **files and file extensions**. It's very fast and simple!

For advanced users and developers, it is possible to use **regular expressions**.

See it in action:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Bulk Rename Utility has a cluttered interface and takes a little getting used to. I recommend [File Renamer Basic](http://download.cnet.com/File-Renamer-Basic/3000-2248_4-11753579.html) you can even preview the output before changing the file names and undo right away, [here](http://www.sherrodcomputers.com/products_filerenamer.cfm#screenshots) are some screenshots.